# Redirect non-www to www version

Tags: redirect

I redirected non-www version to www through .htaccess Rewrite Rule.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.exame.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Now most of the non-www urls have been redirected to www ones. However, there are still some of the pages in non-www version. Why is this? I simply want to redirect all non-www content to www. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue to me.

Comment: Thanks. But when I type in a url without wwww in front, it simply displays without wwww. I am really confused.

Comment: Yes, got that. It might be a caching issue, as said. Clear your browser cache once.

Comment: You are right. After I cleared the cache, all content are in www versions. Thanks a lot for your advice.